# How to make a character jump up with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics

I am trying to work on the mechanics for a game I want to work on, however I don't have much experience with this area of programming.  I have gotten a circle to move smoothly left and right with the A and D keys using requestAnimationFrame(), however I have absolutely no clue what the best approach would be to make the circle "jump" so to speak.

I want the ball to be able to move upwards when W is pressed until a certain height is reached, and then begin to fall down to the ground at a certain rate.  I also want to retain the ability for the ball to move left and right while jumping.  I'm not exactly sure how to go about this as I have little experience with request animation frame(), I've tried cancelling the current animation frame and calling a new one within a jump function but that doesn't seem to work at all.

Here is my code so far:

```
var canvas,
    ctx,
    westX = 300,
    westY = 400,
    velX = 0,
    velY = 0,
    speed = 3,
    jumpSpeed = 2,
    friction = 0.98,
    keys = [],
    jumping = false;


window.onload = function(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  drawLevel();    //intial level draw
}

function drawLevel() {
  move();
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#c3c3d5";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(westX,westY,8,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.fill();
  if (!keys[87] && !keys[32])
  requestAnimationFrame(drawLevel);
  if (keys[87] || keys[32])
    { 
      jump();

    }
}
```

Character Movement:

```
//moves character
function move()
{
  //requestAnimationFrame(move);
  if (keys[65]) {     //if a is pressed
    if (velX > -speed) {
      velX--;
    }
  }
  if (keys[68]) {     //if d is pressed
    if (velX < speed) {
      velX++;
    }
  }
  velX*= friction;
  westX += velX;

  //checks if character is at the edge
  if (westX >= canvas.width-8)
    {
      westX = canvas.width-8;
    } else if (westX <= 8)
      {
        westX = 8;
      }
}
```

Attempt at jump function:

```
function jump()
{
  requestAnimationFrame(jump)
   if (velY > -jumpSpeed) {
      velY--;
    }
    velY*= friction;
    westY += velY;   
  }

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                          keys[e.keyCode] = true;
                          });
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                          keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

Also, here is a codepen link to show what I have working so far:
https://codepen.io/shanetorres/pen/OvRdjq?editors=1010

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the pieces are not arranged correctly.

Divide the character control in two phases: movement calculation, and animation. Think in kinematics: The character's next position is driven by its actual position vector and its current velocity vector.

In the first phase, movement calculation, you alter only the velocity. Left/right modify the horizontal component of the speed, and the jump and gravity modify the vertical component. You want full air control, so both are independent (otherwise, altering the horizontal velocity manipulation would be conditioned by the vertical position, i.e., not jumping/falling). Ignore inertia for the moment (I think that's a better name than friction IMHO). The horizontal velocity `velX` is either `maxVelX`, `-maxVelX`, or `0`, depending on whether right, left, or none/both are pressed. The vertical velocity `velY` is `0` if y is below or exactly a given value (i.e., the floor); when on the floor, pressing jump will set `velY` to `velJump`, and you decrease this value a certain amount every frame (i.e., gravity. Remember that it's an acceleration, i.e., velocity over time). When the character's `y` is below the floor level, you set `velY` to `0` and `y` to the floor level.

Once you have the movement calculated, you apply it to the position (i.e., animate it): `x += velX; y += velY;` This is the second phase of the character control.

Once you have this running, you can add inertia. Horizontal velocity is increased/decreased every frame until its "target" velocity is reached. I'd remove the vertical inertia/movement dampening unless you want your player to get stuck on the air or fall like a feather. However, it's usually a good idea to limit the falling speed to a hard limit if there's a lot of verticality in your game.

This is, of course, an over-simplistic approach to physics (common in most platforming/arcade games). For realistic or more elaborate approaches, I'd consider a 2D physics engine and using forces instead of just velocities.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I needed! I added a maxVelY variable; when W is pressed I set the ball's velocity to that.  I then set a boolean jumping variable to true, and then I check to see if that is true later on and subtract a value from it's velocity.  When the ball is at a certain height, I set jumping to false and it kicks out from updating its movement.

Comment: It looks better now :) If you want a suggestion, I'd adjust (increase) the `maxVelY` and `gravity` values to give it a more arcade-ish feel.

Comment: Also, you can jump mid-air and hold the jump. You usually jump only when on the ground, or, in case you want double-jumps, jump only on the keydown event, not when holding it.

Comment: Ahh, ok that makes sense.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically want to program the physics yourself or is building the game itself your primary goal? If you're not too interested in programming the physics, I'd recommend that you look into [Phaser.io framework](http://phaser.io/) for writing the game. It has physics libraries included, there are tons of tutorials and it's just a good tool to for building HTML games.